# Rcpparmadillo: can't call Fortran routine "dgebal"?

Tags: r, rcpp, lapack

I need to use a Fortran routine called `dgebal` (documentation [here](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/scilab2c/source/tree/1413/tags/release-2.0/src/fortran/lapack/dgebal.f)) in my Rcpparmadillo code. I have included the following headers:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
# include <math.h>
```

However, when I try to compile my code using `sourceCpp()` I get the following error:

```
error: 'dgebal_' was not declared in this scope
```

If I further include `<R_ext/Lapack.h>` and `<R_ext/BLAS.h>`, the code compiles without error and runs fine. However the compiler throws a bunch of warnings like this:

```
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include/R_ext/BLAS.h:49:64: warning: declaration of 'double dasum_(const int*, const double*, const int*)' with C language linkage [enabled by default]
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/library/RCPPAR~1/include/armadillo_bits/def_blas.hpp:76:1: warning: conflicts with previous declaration 'double arma::dasum_(arma::blas_int*, const double*, arma::blas_int*)' [enabled by default]
```

There are many more warnings similar to this. Am I correct to assume this is caused by the LAPACK library shipped with Rcpparmadillo not including `dgebal`, which is however included with R's LAPACK library? Should I be concerned with these warnings? And finally, is there any way to use `dgebal` in my Rcpparmadillo code without compilation warnings? Both Rcpp and Rcpparmadillo are up to date. Operating system is Windows 8.1 64bit.

EDIT:
Thanks @coatless and @Dirk Eddelbuettel for pointing out that this is not an Rcpparmadillo issue. Nevertheless my problem persists and I would like suggestions on how to get around this. Below is a working example code illustrating my problem. It compiles fine but produces a lot of the aforementioned warnings, which does not seem to affect the intended functionality, at least according to my limited testing. If I remove the two headers `R_ext/Lapack.h` and `R_ext/BLAS.h`, the compiler throws the aforementioned error.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <R_ext/Lapack.h>
#include <R_ext/BLAS.h>


// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List R_dgebal2(SEXP x)
{
  SEXP dims, z, Scale, i_1, i_2;
  int n, info;

  dims = Rf_getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol);
  n = INTEGER(dims)[0];


  z = Rf_duplicate(x); Scale = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, n);
  i_1 = Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, 1); i_2 = Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, 1);

  F77_CALL(dgebal)("B", &n, REAL(z), &n, INTEGER(i_1), INTEGER(i_2),
           REAL(Scale), &info);

  arma::mat zz = as<arma::mat>(wrap(z));
  arma::vec scale2 = as<arma::vec>(wrap(Scale));
  int i1=as<int>(wrap(i_1)), i2=as<int>(wrap(i_2));
  return List::create(_["z"]=zz, _["scale"]=scale2, _["i1"]=i1, _["i2"]=i2);

}

// Test in R
/*** R
Q <- matrix(c(-1.918206e-01,5.999147e-01,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,1.106148e-01,
              -1.152574e+00,5.716490e-01,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,5.526595e-01,
              -1.256864e+00,3.905685e+04,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,1.929101e-01,
              -3.905721e+04,0.000000e+00,8.120577e-02,0.000000e+00,4.923053e-01,3.572873e-01,0.000000e+00),
              nrow = 5, byrow = T)
R_dgebal2(Q)
*/
```

Comment: RcppArmadillo uses R's LAPACK installation. Why are you trying to access a fortran routine?

Comment: _"LAPACK library shipped with Rcpparmadillo"_ Completely wrong.  RcppArmadillo never *ever* ships LAPACK but relies on the LAPACK R knows / was built with which _can_ be a local copy.  This has been discussed a million times, see here, at the GH repo (issues) and on the list.  If you were to supply a _complete_ example we could test on OS X and Linux.

Comment: @coatless: Because I need to do matrix balancing, which is not readily available in armadillo. The Fortran routine `dgebal` does this.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Thanks for pointing that out. I apologize for my misunderstanding of how LAPACK linking works in Rcpparmadillo. I have added a working example illustrating my problem.

Comment: I don't anything about `dgebal` in particular, but the _general_ fix to needed some extra is to link against (if a library has it; doesn't seem to be the case with the LAPACK we use here) or to included it yourself in your package.  Now, there are some issue having both Fortran and C++ in the same package; see the R documentation.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Could you please point me to the link of the R documentation where the specifics are? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I have figured this out. I just created a local header file with the following lines and #included it in my .cpp file. Compiles fine with no warnings or errors.

```
#ifdef ARMA_USE_LAPACK

#if !defined(ARMA_BLAS_CAPITALS)

 #define arma_dgebal dgebal

#else
 #define arma_dgebal DGEBAL

#endif

extern "C"
void arma_fortran(arma_dgebal)(char* job, int* n, double* a, int* lda,
                  int* ilo, int* ihi, double* scale, int* info);

#endif
```

Comment: Congratulations, you worked out how to call a Fortran routine in Lapack not already accessed by Armadillo using its framework.   That is useful to have here, so I just upvoted it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Thanks for the upvote. I imagine this is probably not a very commonly seen issue but it'll be nice to have an simple and generalizable solution in case others need it too.